# Workaround for running McAfee ePO and WSUS on Same Server

Tags: iis, wsus, mcafee

I've come across a predicament recently where when WSUS requires IIS and MS Web Publishing Service. At the same time my anti-virus McAfee ePO requires Apache and some other web services to run in order to access the web console for management of that.

**Is there a hack or trick to allowing Apache and IIS to run simultaneously on the same server at the same time without causing issues between each other?**

I spoke with a McAfee support individual and they were unaware of any means of running these services at the same time. They only could recommend running WSUS on a different server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick would be to run the Apache and IIS on different ports (only one service can bind to one port at a time), though there's far from any guarantee that WSUS or ePO would work properly on non-standard ports.

McAfee's support was correct in recommending not running the two things on the same server, though both pieces of software do have options for changing their various communication ports from the standard value, if you're feeling adventurous, or have no other choice.

- [ePO 4.x port list](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB66797).
- [McAfee KB for changing the agent-server communication port](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB67605) (default is 80)
- [`By default, a WSUS server that is configured for the default Web site uses port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. By default, the WSUS server uses port 8530 for HTTP and port 8531 for HTTPS if it is using the WSUS custom Web site.`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/8907dd07-8cc2-4aec-b542-d52e4691ba1e/how-to-change-port-settings-in-wsus)
- [There are couple decent answer here about changing the ports WSUS uses](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/8907dd07-8cc2-4aec-b542-d52e4691ba1e/how-to-change-port-settings-in-wsus), but it seem like it would just be easier to have a custom WSUS site.

Comment: So I don't understand why he didn't recommend changing the operating ports. Is that because it's not guaranteed that they'd work properly on non-standard ports?

Comment: @gh0st Maybe.  I'd bet it's because he gets paid $12 an hour to read from a script, though.  Not a good idea to expect too much from tier 1 tech support.

Answer (score -1):

I confirm that it work good by changing the epo port during it's installation. Did it in like 6 soho office. Not a bestpractice.

See the printscreen [epo+wsus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INmDF.png)